# Better example of an infinitely differentiable function which doesn't have the Taylor series expansion than $e^{-1/x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, taylor-expansion, power-series

Every source I've looked at gives the same example of the function $e^{-1/x^2}$. Since this function has a singularity at $x=0$, where we center the Taylor expansion for this example, it doesn't even seem like a good example. (I know that we manually define it as $0$ at $x=0$, but still, it seems like cheating to me.) Aren't there some better examples without singularity? Why is this example even so ubiquitous?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can alternatively define $f(x) = \exp(-1/x)$ for $x>0$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\leq 0$. But the example is almost the same as before.

When you say, "better examples", you probably want something that involves the standard "*elementary*" functions that do not require you to manually define the function as something different. The problem is that if $f$ and $g$ are two analytic functions which are defined in a neighborhood of $p$, then $f\pm g$ and $f\cdot g$ will also be analytic in the neighborhood of $p$. And if $g(p)\not = 0$ then $\frac{1}{g}$ is also analytic in that neighborhood. Therefore, you cannot just take the usual standard calculus functions (which we call the "*elementary*" functions) and combine them together to form something which is not analytic, because the elementary functions are all analytic at every point in a neighborhood.

Comment: Thank you! I guess I see now. So there are completely no way to make this example without resorting to a piecewise-defined function?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what it is means, you cannot produce a "simple" example. But, if you think about it, can you produce a "simple" example of a function which is not continuous?